# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException The link is force detached. Code: RenewToken

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-3.1

I am getting below exception from topic's subscription.

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+d__86.MoveNext

The link 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:source(address:XXXXXXXXXXXX/Subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX):MessageReceiver2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX' is force detached. Code: RenewToken. Details: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXX/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXX'.. TrackingId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:XXXXXXXXXXXX The link 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:source(address:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX):MessageReceiver2XXXXXXXXXX/Subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX' is force detached. Code: RenewToken. Details: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://XXXXXXXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/XXXXXXXXX/subscriptions/XXXXXX'.. TrackingId:XXXXXXXXXXXXX, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm  whether you have configured the Managed Identity for authentication in your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#built-in-rbac-roles-for-azure-service-bus
As per the error message  ‘Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation’ , looks like the RBAC role is not assigned correctly for the operation that you are performing. If you are receiving the messages, then please assigned the RBAC ‘Azure Service Bus Data Receiver’ role or verify the built-in RBAC roles for Azure service bus:

1. Azure Service Bus Data Owner: Enables data access to Service Bus namespace and its entities (queues, topics, subscriptions, and filters)
2. Azure Service Bus Data Sender: Use this role to give send access to Service Bus namespace and its entities.
3. Azure Service Bus Data Receiver: Use this role to give receiving access to Service Bus namespace and its entities.

Once you have verified and assign the right role please test it and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Azure function connect service bus through primary connection string.  The above exception often occurs once or twice a day